# go jwt ValidationKeyGetter does not compile

Tags: go, jwt, jwt-go

I am new to go.  I am trying to set up a secure webserver using go and jwt, but I cannot get this to compile:

```
mw := jwtmiddleware.New(jwtmiddleware.Options{
        ValidationKeyGetter: func (token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return mySigningKey, nil
        },
        SigningMethod: jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
    })
```

but I only get the following error (from the compiler and the analyzer):

```
cannot use func literal (type func(*"webserver/vendor/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go".Token) (interface {}, error)) as type "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go".Keyfunc in field value
```

I have tried making it a separate named func but that didn't help.  The jwt library shows

```
type Keyfunc func(*Token) (interface{}, error)
```

so, it should match the signature.  The code is the same in several online examples including `auth0.com`.

I have had success running simpler go programs, including serving a simple web page, so the compiler is working correctly.

Running on ubuntu 18.04 with the newest stable version of go and packages (downloaded and installed a few days ago).  Thanks

Comment: Your code is using a version of the jwt import from the vendor directory but it is expecting it to come from the un-vendored directory (note the difference in the error message type). This suggests to me that jwtmiddleware is not in your vendor directory. What do you use for dependency management?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the package was not in vendor/github.com.  I did the following:

```
cp -R ../github.com/auth0 vendor/github.com/auth0
```

and it now compiles.

Comment: Do not do this, instead do a `dep ensure`, that will get the code to your vendor, and its usually a release type. If you've copied the code from go home, its usually master branch and isn't recommended for any stable codebase.

Comment: I ran dep ensure and got no errors or, for that matter, output of any kind.  I presume it saw the directory I copied and thought it was OK.  I'm sure I didn't set things up perfectly, but it is working now.  Thanks.